# CSS animation not smooth enough

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

The animation is moving linearly from left to right but starts abruptly once the animation time is over. Tried with reducing to 1s and increasing the time to 15s. And even increased the keyframes but still doesn't work. Please help:

```css
.grid-item-2 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  background-image: url(Building_1.png);
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 53px;
  width: 90%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  animation: Buildings 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes Buildings {
  0% { background-position: 0% 100%; }
  25% { background-position: 25% 75%; }
  50% { background-position: 50% 50%; }
  75% { background-position: 75% 25%; }
  100% { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-item grid-item-2"></div>
```

Comment: try `animation: Buildings 2s linear infinite alternate;`

Comment: it's supposed to be buildings moving so that a car in front of it looks that it's in motion. can't do alternate

Comment: share your full code with the image you are using so we can see

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the jumping is that you need to adapt the background image to the size of the div element, which can be hard if you want to have a responsive site. The code below is the best I can come up with, where I loop between -100% and 200%, making the image start outside the element and then end outside the other side of the element, creating the illusion that it continues. I would honestly replace `repeat-x` with just `repeat`.

I added a background color just to make the element more visible.

```css
.grid-item-2 {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/737/300/200.jpg");
/*  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 53px; */
  width: 90%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  animation: Buildings 3s linear infinite;
  
  background-color: #000; /* just to show case the element better */
  height: 90vh;
}

@keyframes Buildings {
  0% { background-position: -100% 200%; }
  100% { background-position: 200% -100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-item-2">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Getting rid of the intermediary keyframes would make it smoother. You only need the frames at 0% and 100%. When you set the animation timing function to linear, it will automatically make sure that all the keyframes that you defined are met. The animation should look something like this...

```
@keyframes Buildings {
    0% {
      background-position: 0% 100%;
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 100% 0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: The OP states: "The animation is moving linearly from left to right but _starts abruptly once the animation time is over_".

Comment: Hi Musab, the animation restarts from 0% once it completes one iteration. I want it to start where it completes, in the previous iteration

Comment: Hey Suparna, all you have to do is add the word 'alternate' after defining the animation to get that effect. So now your animation definition will read ```animation: Buildings 2s linear infinite alternate;```

Comment: @SuparnaBose What this does is reverse the animation every time it is played. So the first time, the background will start at the top left and move to the bottom right, then it'll move from the bottom right back to the top left, and repeat that pattern. Since you're using a **linear** timing function, it will still look a little jerky at the ends, so I would recommend switching it with **ease-in-out** making the definition now read ```animation: Buildings 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;``` Now it'll move faster towards the middle of the animation and slow down before changing direction.